# how to parallelize Outer function in r?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, outer-join

I want to build a matrix of similarity of various objects in a list using outer function and do it in an effective way using parallelized code. In another way, how to parallelize FUN in outer where
matrix <- outer(X, Y, FUN,...)

I am using Rstudio Version 1.2.1335 with R x64 3.6.1 on Windows. 
and here's a simple code example:

```
my_list <- list("a"=c("A", "B", "C") , "b"=c("B", "A", "D"), "c"=c("C", "A", "D"), "d"=c("D", "B", "C"))

my_matrix <- outer(my_list, my_list, Vectorize(function(x,y) getsimilarityscore(x,y), vectorize.args = c("x", "y")))
```

I am expecting a matrix with scores of similarity.

Comment: There might be better options but one way would be to generate combinations first and then you can use any parallel implementation to apply your function over the combinations.

Comment: You can use a nested foreach call. Here, I don't think `outer` is helping as your function is not really vectorized.

Comment: I wonder if the `future` package would help in writing a function that could go into `outer()`.

Comment: I tried foreach before but it gave me many matrices instead of one. Thanks @F.Privé I tried nested foreach and it worked very well.

Comment: @MahmoudFassad You can provide your solution if others have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried a nested foreach as suggested by @F. Prive! and it worked well. 
Here's the code I used:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster("number of cores")
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
my_matrix <- foreach(i = my_list, .combine = 'cbind', .packages = 'yourSimilarityPackage') %:%
  foreach(j = my_ist, .combine = 'c', .packages = 'yourSimilarityPackage') %dopar% {
    getsimilarityscore(i, j)
  }
stopCluster(cl = NULL)
```

then you will need to change the col and rows names of the matrix