# Significant correlations between two dataframes

Tags: r, performance, matrix, correlation

I want to find a significant correlation between two large dataframes (FDR < 0.05). How do I modify the code to run faster? The `cor.mtest(cor)` has taken several hours.
Running on a small dataset such as the sample below did not take a long time, unlike when ran on the original dataset.

```
t.bval <- t(bval)
t.expr <- t(expr)
cor <- cor(t.bval, t.expr)
colnames(cor) <- rownames(bval)
mtest <- cor.mtest(cor)
adjusted.pval <- p.adjust(mtest$p, method = "fdr")
sig.cor <- cor * (adjusted.pval < 0.05)
```

Input:

```
> dim(bval)
[1] 9844  174
> dim(expr)
[1] 9844  174

> dput(t(bval)[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0.651202886519379, 0.546932468275249, 0.77990670335116, 
0.570367878904668, 0.490859703406345, 0.819127800066518, 0.896778785060273, 
0.910419995766152, 0.862881750710962, 0.895738407255165, 0.409754021776346, 
0.437562413240227, 0.404271790048482, 0.407834330819103, 0.411767445153759, 
0.111173024032316, 0.0732396067281633, 0.0892561968208864, 0.0924103940922992, 
0.0745261480840073, 0.727502771503466, 0.745126721066948, 0.72446467629277, 
0.740169892735761, 0.730258358871385), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01"), c("A1BG", "A2M", "A4GALT", 
    "AAAS", "AACS")))

> dput(t(expr)[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(3.11327062985085, 2.60736439071998, 2.51138760850467, 
2.61757871821215, 2.99116809570192, 3.94027812075928, 3.7456302068644, 
3.48141956715802, 3.70450896566585, 3.58083202637968, 3.50763791284198, 
3.60784204549275, 3.45528021497798, 3.56318932299471, 3.53594747333992, 
3.47014111307111, 3.4842944131813, 3.44268580438446, 3.5016009268885, 
3.51798634683037, 3.38519953102602, 3.45448967582629, 3.42698278688777, 
3.44786587002075, 3.38755257891847), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01"), c("A1BG", "A2M", "A4GALT", 
    "AAAS", "AACS")))
```

Comment: `cor.mtest` is probably from a package that you have not named.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cor.test` in an `outer` based approach might be faster.

```
> f <- \(x, y) unname(unlist(cor.test(t_bval[, x], t_expr[, y])[c('estimate', 'p.value')]))
> o <- outer(colnames(t_bval), colnames(t_expr), Vectorize(f, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
> res <- array(unlist(o), c(2, ncol(t_bval), ncol(t_bval)), 
+               dimnames=list(c('estimate', 'p.value'), colnames(t_bval), colnames(t_expr))) |> 
+     aperm(c(2, 3, 1))
```

If it's still too slow, you may parallelize the double `for` loop<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57709182/6574038)</sup>.

```
> library(doParallel)
> cl <- makeForkCluster(detectCores() - 1)
> registerDoParallel(cl)
> o <- foreach(i=colnames(t_bval)) %:% foreach(j=colnames(t_expr)) %dopar% f(i, j)
> stopCluster(cl)
> 
> res <- array(unlist(o), c(2, ncol(t_bval), ncol(t_bval)), 
+               dimnames=list(c('estimate', 'p.value'), colnames(t_bval), colnames(t_expr))) |> 
+     aperm(c(3, 2, 1))
```

Finally add the `p.adjust` like so.

```
> array(c(res, p.adjust(res[,,'p.value'], 'BH')), 
+       dim=dim(res) + c(0, 0, 1), 
+       dimnames=Map(base::c, dimnames(res), list(NULL, NULL, 'p.adj')))
, , estimate

             A1BG        A2M       A4GALT        AAAS        AACS
A1BG   -0.3340301 -0.2073497 -0.795970221 -0.95086519  0.02340409
A2M    -0.6496883 -0.8823652 -0.002401227 -0.04327964  0.40087554
A4GALT -0.1639098  0.2617615  0.794526178  0.18380488  0.45462281
AAAS    0.3873550  0.5799259 -0.477426368 -0.42213266 -0.36907517
AACS   -0.3583838  0.2423275  0.950708293  0.45917286  0.73001439

, , p.value

            A1BG        A2M     A4GALT       AAAS      AACS
A1BG   0.5827465 0.73789833 0.10718028 0.01297749 0.9702037
A2M    0.2353765 0.04756878 0.99694267 0.94491186 0.5036101
A4GALT 0.7922419 0.67056113 0.10829500 0.76729686 0.4417647
AAAS   0.5194314 0.30539340 0.41607679 0.47894313 0.5409767
AACS   0.5536569 0.69450596 0.01303939 0.43661144 0.1614075

, , p.adj

            A1BG       A2M    A4GALT      AAAS      AACS
A1BG   0.8569802 0.9002749 0.5414750 0.1629924 0.9969427
A2M    0.8406304 0.3964065 0.9969427 0.9969427 0.8569802
A4GALT 0.9002749 0.9002749 0.5414750 0.9002749 0.8569802
AAAS   0.8569802 0.8569802 0.8569802 0.8569802 0.8569802
AACS   0.8569802 0.9002749 0.1629924 0.8569802 0.6725312
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(t_bval)
structure(c(0.651202886519379, 0.546932468275249, 0.77990670335116, 
0.570367878904668, 0.490859703406345, 0.819127800066518, 0.896778785060273, 
0.910419995766152, 0.862881750710962, 0.895738407255165, 0.409754021776346, 
0.437562413240227, 0.404271790048482, 0.407834330819103, 0.411767445153759, 
0.111173024032316, 0.0732396067281633, 0.0892561968208864, 0.0924103940922992, 
0.0745261480840073, 0.727502771503466, 0.745126721066948, 0.72446467629277, 
0.740169892735761, 0.730258358871385), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01"), c("A1BG", "A2M", "A4GALT", 
    "AAAS", "AACS")))
> dput(t_expr)
structure(c(3.11327062985085, 2.60736439071998, 2.51138760850467, 
2.61757871821215, 2.99116809570192, 3.94027812075928, 3.7456302068644, 
3.48141956715802, 3.70450896566585, 3.58083202637968, 3.50763791284198, 
3.60784204549275, 3.45528021497798, 3.56318932299471, 3.53594747333992, 
3.47014111307111, 3.4842944131813, 3.44268580438446, 3.5016009268885, 
3.51798634683037, 3.38519953102602, 3.45448967582629, 3.42698278688777, 
3.44786587002075, 3.38755257891847), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01"), c("A1BG", "A2M", "A4GALT", 
    "AAAS", "AACS")))
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I want to return a matrix with a significant correlation (FDR 0.05) but your code returns an array. How do I extract the matrix?

Comment: @jay.sf if I may ask, why are you in all your answers copying the dput of the data from the question to your answer? Also I'll take the opportunity to introduce you to the {constructive} package that offers a readable alternative to dput() :   https://github.com/cynkra/constructive. I've been using it to edit many SO questions.

Comment: `reprex::reprex()` and `reprex:::prex()` might also help you make your answers easier to reproduce since the console copy and pastes need some tweaking.

Comment: @moodymudskipper Actually, I'm not copying OP's data, but the data I used, so my answer is self-contained. Sometimes they can be identical of course. Over the years on SO, I have learned that sometimes OP's data is changed and my answer would otherwise no longer be reproducible. In this answer, for example, I use `t_bval` and `t_expr`, which are not used in the OP.

Comment: @moodymudskipper Editing OP (and also answer) data is a [grey area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370968/6574038), I've noticed you did it once with my answer data, please don't do it. `dput` is pretty standard to share data and works perfect for me, not seeing any benefits for a package for this task. Apart from personal preferences, it provides all data in the same `structure` format. BTW, note, that "reprex" ads [shouldn't be used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386886/6574038) on SO.

Comment: Fair enough. I find it confusing because either your dput is the same as OP's and then it's redundant, or it's different and we can't tell unless we execute both, since dput is so hard to read. The post you link to talks about the reprex footer AFAICT, I agree it should be removed. Your contributions are obviously valued, I think it's too bad that we can't just copy and paste them, esp since you worry about self contained. Me editing your answer was a mistake sorry about that. Thanks for answering.